# Why only is a PID controller used in ROS Control?

Tags: control, ros, pid, joint, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the `ros_control` set of packages, why PID controller specifically is used in `joint_state_controller`, `joint_position_controller`, and `joint_velocity_controller` ? Why not any other control algorithms like MPC and LQR ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365407/why-only-is-a-pid-controller-used-in-ros-control-?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2020-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple: because they worked sufficiently well for the (original) developers/maintainers of those packages, and no one else has made an effort to contribute more advanced algorithms.

If you see an opportunity to contribute something, please do.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing to consider is that PID controllers can run without needing a model of the system. You cannot do LQR or MPC control without at least a half-decent model of your system. PID controllers can be tuned in-the-loop and thus you can simply tune your gains in simulation or on hardware.

---

Originally posted by [navdlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/60283/navdlee/) with karma: 61 on 2020-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1